# Laravel - Inertia - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

How to use Laravel - Inertia - ReactJS but using routing from ReactJS? The project is made into one folder, but uses the Restfull API concept. Basically I'm Back-End, so I've learn to be full stack dev.

I have tried using ReactJS Router but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

inertiajs lets laravel handle routing, so what I suggest is to get your index page using `Inertia::render()` and then make the rest of the calls using Axios.

Comment: Then, how about storing the csrf token during the authentication process? Does it have to use the API?

Comment: sorry for the late replay, to handle authentication I assume you are going to use Laravel Breeze, with interejs it gets Handel automatically you don't have to worry about it, in your laravel code you get access to the auth variable and Middleware, and in you vue/react file you also get access to auth, this auth is updated with every request and can be found and changes in `HandleInertiaRequests.php` file also known as Shared data. i suggest you take a look at this link as they did explain it better than me [link](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data)